# How to rewrite $R^TAR = V$ to find $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

How to write the following equation to find $V$, the eigenvalue matrix. Note that $R$ is the orthogonal eigenvector matrix, and $A$ is one of the symmetric matrices.

Comment: Is $R$ assumed to be orthogonal or at least invertible? Otherwise there won't be a unique solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "E is the orthogonal eigenvector matrix"? Should that be R instead?

Comment: My apologies for the typo -- yes, I meant that R is the orthogonal eigenvector matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that we have $R^TAR = V$, and $R$ is an orthogonal matrix. It follows that
$$
R^TAR = V \implies\\
R(R^TAR) = RV \implies\ \\
AR = RV \implies\\
(AR)R^T = (RV)R^T \implies\\
A = RVR^T.
$$